# Keep changes in subfolder across all git branches

Tags: git, git-branch

I work on a project with a lot of branches.

In my project folder I have a currently untracked folder that needs to be accessible from all branches. It contains a bunch of scripts that simulates the production environment but cuts down execution times of program calls that would otherwise take hours. These scripts are constantly refined to emulate the production environment more accurately.

I want to track this folder in my repo, but any changes I make to it, need to be accessible from any branch. How can I track this folder but still have it behave like it was untracked?

Answer (score 2):

If changes to this directory are orthogonal to changes in other directories, perhaps it should live in a different Git repository.

You can just check out that other repository into the right place inside the main one, but then everyone who wants to use the scripts will need to check it out into the same place (not necessarily a huge problem).

If you want to get fancier, check out [Git submodules](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-submodule). However, a submodule does exist at a specified commit, so that's probably not suitable for your case.

Comment: With git submodule he would have to update every branch when a new commit is done in the submodule. Either with a merge or a rebase the result is the same of having the scripts tracked in the same repo, so as you said, this is not suitable for his case. I would use a different repo.

Comment: For clarification when you say I need to update a branch after a commit to the submodule, that means i have a new merge commit or rebase for every time I update the submodule in the branch.

Comment: That's why I said that submodules are probably not suitable :) I just thought I'd mention them for completeness.